# Tastypie + Backbone: model.save (PUT) fails (Until I open the resource via browser)

Tags: python, backbone.js, tastypie

I am working with Django-Tastypie and Backbone and there is a problem when saving models, for some reason the operation fails.

API:

```
class InboxResource(ModelResource):
user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

class Meta:
    queryset = Email.objects.filter( Q(spam = False) & Q(archive = False) ).order_by('-date')
    limit = 0
    always_return_data = True
    authentication = CustomAuthentication()
    authorization = CustomAuthorization()
```

BACKBONE function:

```
set_spam: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.model.set({ 'spam': true });
    this.model.save();
    console.log('spam set');
    $(this.parent).fadeOut();
    $(this.el).fadeOut();
},
```

Console:

> PUT 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/inbox/7  jquery-1.7.1.js:8102
>
> jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery-1.7.1.js:8102 jQuery.extend.ajax
>
> jquery-1.7.1.js:7580 Backbone.sync backbone.js:1355
>
> _.extend.save backbone.js:392
>
> Backbone.View.extend.set_spam Views.Single.js:41
>
> jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.1.js:3256
>
> jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle

When inspecting the model after the operation, its value actually changes, so I infer the problem could be related to Tastypie.

There is something strange though; when I go via browser to a specific resource, say "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/inbox/7", it is correctly displayed as expected. However, if after that I try the exact same operation, this time works! so I confess I am bit puzzled with this.

Any ideas will be well appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm running in a similar problem as well. When I do a PUT I get a 500 error but the values actually change ! Did you solve the issue?